# Problem when trying to iterate through a string array for execSQL

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, iteration

**How do I do this: (why does it not work? - Emulator ends app without error message)**

```
String [] aSQL;
aSQL = new String[50];

aSQL[0] = "CREATE TABLE tbl_team ("+
    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
    "teamName TEXT NOT NULL);";

aSQL[1] = "CREATE TABLE tbl_cardType ("+
    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
    "cardTypeName TEXT NOT NULL);";

for (int i = 0; i < aSQL.length; i++){
    db.execSQL(aSQL[i]);
}
```

**instead of having to do this:**

```
db.execSQL(aSQL[0])
db.execSQL(aSQL[1])
```

If anybody wants to know why I am trying to do it this way. It is because I am on a tight schedule and don't know another way. I have tried and failed at making the database in SQLite browser. Putting it in assets folder and copying it over during install.

There are of course a lot more than 2 SQL commands to run.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does your logcat say? You say the emulator ends your app without any error message. Usually the emulator just says Force Close or ANR.

Comment: Have looked in LogCat can't see a problem, no red lines, says terminated by signal (11). I usually get error messages like you mention but not in this instance, thanks

Comment: Just being naive - the way it's written, doesn't it also try to do `db.execSQL(aSQL[2])` (then 3,4,...) which would fail as aSQL[2] isn't initialized? aSQL.length would be 50, wouldn't it?

Comment: Joubarc is probably right.  It is my misunderstanding over whether .length gives array size or how many variables have been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a create_tables.sql file in assets, and then execute it on app start, like this:

```
InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("create_tables.sql"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(getDatabasePath("database.sqlite").getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE|SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
String l;
while ((l = br.readLine()) != null) db.execSQL(l);
```

**Update:**

Okay so let's say you have

```
class MyApp extends Application {
  public static Application appContext;
  public void oncreate() { 
    appContext = this;

  }
}
```

And then anywhere you can do almost as above

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MyApp.appContext.getAssets().open("create_tables.sql")));
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this. It says the getAssets and getDatabasePath methods are undefined. Are you saying to put this in my main class and not my DbAdapter class? If so it is going to run this every time the app runs I don't wan't that and thought I should be running this sort of stuff from the DbAdapter class that handles database on create and update .  I'm sorry I am new to Java/Android programming and confused. Thanks

Comment: getAssets and getDatabasePath are methods of Context, so just pass a Context (Activity and Application instances are contexts) to your DbAdapter.

Comment: thanks for this I will try it out on Monday and provide feedback

Comment: I have took another look at this but still don't understand. I tried prefixing with this and many other things I'm not just being lazy.  I don't have time to learn the details of everything like what are things such as; methods and Contexts and passing Context before I write my android app.  I need to learn this stuff as I go and am hoping you or others in this community can help me.  Many Thanks